# Why is my OpenSSL-generated signature different than the signature from PyCryptodome?

Tags: python, bash, openssl

I'm trying to validate a signature from OpenSSL's [`rsautl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsautl.html) command with [PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The Bash command I use to sign the data (data is "38b..da1" string) is:

```
echo 38b2be8850bbf6e52bee4d4c5889df436285479f5472efe856787d7068a50da1 | openssl rsautl -inkey another_guys_priv_key.pem -sign | base64
```

I have converted this command into a Python script so I can compare things in Python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from shlex import split

# Use openssl to sign the data ("38b2..0da1") with another_guys private key
p1 = Popen(split('echo 38b2be8850bbf6e52bee4d4c5889df436285479f5472efe856787d7068a50da1'), stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(split('openssl rsautl -inkey another_guys_priv_key.pem -sign'), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output, _ = p2.communicate()
```

Then I use PyCryptodome to sign the same data and compare the signatures:

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# Use PyCrypto to sign the data with another_guys private key
key = RSA.importKey(open('another_guys_priv_key.pem').read())
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)

h = SHA256.new()
h.update('38b2be8850bbf6e52bee4d4c5889df436285479f5472efe856787d7068a50da1'.encode('utf-8'))
signature = signer.sign(h)

# Compare signature with OpenSSL signature
output == signature  # False
```

and the results aren't the same.

So I was thinking that maybe OpenSSL automatically converts hexadecimal data into bytes and signs that, so I tried it with Python:

```
from binascii import unhexlify

# Use PyCryptodome to sign the hex-decoded data with another_guys private key
hh = SHA256.new()
hh.update(unhexlify('38b2be8850bbf6e52bee4d4c5889df436285479f5472efe856787d7068a50da1'))
hex_signature = signer.sign(hh)

# Compare signature with OpenSSL signature
output == hex_signature  # False
```

but those results aren't the same either.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm not familiar enough with the Python crypto libraries to figure out what it is. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` command (or shell built-in) adds a new line to the output by default, so signatures never match. Try disabling it.

```
$ echo -n foo | wc -c # hint - this counts number of bytes
3
$ echo foo | wc -c
4
```

But personally, I would just pass the string as standard input to the second process directly.